# regular expression for telephone/mobile per country and variable naming

Tags: java, regex, formatting

would like to know if there is a better approach in doing a telephone/mobile number regular expression for specific country. this includes naming variables like how to know if format is international format (is it with + sign?), a national format (is it the area code enclosed in parenthesis) or a local format (no + sign, and no area code), currently they are labelled as country_name_telephone/country_name_mobile or country_name_telephone_N_digit, etc...

below are the regular expression for some country.

```
/** matches the following pattern:
 * - 01-111-11-11
 * - 01 111 11 11
 * - 011-11-11-11
 * - 011 11 11 11
 * - 011111111
 */
public final static String CTRY_BELGIUM_TELEPHONE = "^0(\\d{8}|\\d\\s\\d{3}\\s\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d|\\d-\\d{3}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d|\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d|\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d)$";

/** matches the following pattern:
 * - 0412-34-56-78
 * - 0412 34 56 78
 * - 0412-345-678
 * - 0412 345 678
 * - 0412345678
 */
public final static String CTRY_BELGIUM_MOBILE = "^04\\d\\d(\\d{6}|\\s\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d|\\s\\d{3}\\s\\d{3}|-\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d|-\\d{3}-\\d{3})$";

/** matches the following pattern:
 * - 0000-0000
 * - 0000 0000
 * - 00000000
 */
public final static String CTRY_HONG_KONG_TELEPHONE = "^(\\d{4}[-\\s]?\\d{4})$";

/** matches the following pattern:
 * - +852-0000-0000
 * - +852 0000 0000
 * - +85200000000
 */
public final static String CTRY_HONG_KONG_MOBILE = "^\\+852(\\d{8}|-\\d{4}-\\d{4}|\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{4})$";

/** matches the following pattern:
 * - 212-0000
 * - 212 0000
 * - 2120000
 */
public final static String CTRY_UNITED_STATES_TELEPHONE_7_DIGIT = "^[2-9]((?!11)\\d{2})[-\\s]*\\d{4}$";

/** matches the following pattern:
 * - 200 212 0000
 * - 200-212-0000
 * - 2002120000
 */
public final static String CTRY_UNITED_STATES_TELEPHONE_10_DIGIT = "^[2-9]\\d{2}((-[2-9]((?!11)\\d{2})-)|(\\s[2-9]((?!11)\\d{2})\\s)|([2-9]((?!11)\\d{2})))\\d{4}$";

/** matches the following pattern:
 * - all matches in CTRY_UNITED_STATES_TELEPHONE_7_DIGIT and CTRY_UNITED_STATES_TELEPHONE_10_DIGIT
 */
public final static String CTRY_UNITED_STATES_TELEPHONE = "("+CTRY_UNITED_STATES_TELEPHONE_7_DIGIT+")|("+CTRY_UNITED_STATES_TELEPHONE_10_DIGIT+")";

/** matches the following pattern:
 * - +1 200 212 0000
 * - +1-200-212-0000
 * - +12002120000
 */
public final static String CTRY_UNITED_STATES_MOBILE = "^\\+1((-[2-9]\\d{2}-[2-9]((?!11)\\d{2})-)|(\\s[2-9]\\d{2}\\s[2-9]((?!11)\\d{2})\\s)|([2-9]\\d{2}[2-9]((?!11)\\d{2})))\\d{4}$";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CTRY_BELGIUM_TELEPHONE`:

First, to understand what the regex is doing, I'll add the railroad diagram

[image: RegEx RailRoad Diagram]

[**Demo on RegEx101**](https://regex101.com/r/HSqiQR/1/)

What it matches:

Zero followed by

1. Eight Digits
2. Digit-Space-Three_Digits-Space-Two_Digits-Space-Two_Digits
3. Digit-Hyphen-Three_Digits-Hyphen-Two_Digits-Hyphen-Two_Digits
4. Two_Digits-Space-Two_Digits-Space-Two_Digits-Space-Two_Digits
5. Two_Digits-Hyphen-Two_Digits-Hyphen-Two_Digits-Hyphen-Two_Digits

Now, looking at above, we can easily spot that many of the things are use multiple times in the same sub-pattern.

**Can we combine/reuse them?**

For simplicity, I'll use single backslash from here onward. You need to escape it by prepending another backslash to escape it in string.

When I say *nth road*, it'll refer to the nth path in the above diagram.

### Review:

The **first road** is straight forward. Match eight digits. Simple!

The **second road**, `\d\s\d{3}\s\d\d\s\d\d`. As you've used `\d{3}`, similarly we can write `\d\d` as `\d{2}`. Cool!

It'll now become `\d\s\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}`.

The **third road** similarly can be written as `\d-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}`.

For fourth and fifth road, same can be used.

Second and Third roads are similar except the separator used between digits. Is there any way to combine them?

[Back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

How can back-reference be used here?

I'll show you: The character should be captured in capturing group and refer it with back-reference whenever needed.

```
\d([\s-])\d{3}\1\d{2}\1\d{2}
```

The regex here can be used to match both second and third road.

1. `\d`: Match a digit
2. `([\s-])`: Match either a space character or hyphen and add it into first capturing group
3. `\d{n}`: Match digits *n* times.
4. `\1`: Match whatever is in first captured group(see #2 above)

There still is repetition in `\1\d{2}\1\d{2}`. This can be added in group and repeated twice `(?:\1\d{2})`. Since, back-reference is used, it's not better to use non-capturing group.(*You'll know why in the 4th and 5th road*).

Similarly, for fourth and fifth road, the regex will be

```
\d{2}([\s-])\d{2}(?:\1\d{2}){2}
```

At this stage, the regex will become

```
^0(?:\d{8}|\d([\s-]?)\d{3}(?:\1\d{2}){2}|\d{2}([\s-])\d{2}(?:\2\d{2}){2})$
```

The first part `\d{8}` can also be removed by using `?` quantifier on the first captured group. By doing this, we're making the `[\s-]` optional and thus `\1` will be empty and will match eight digits with no spaces between them.

So, **Final RegEx** is

```
/^0(?:\d([\s-]?)\d{3}(?:\1\d{2}){2}|\d{2}([\s-])\d{2}(?:\2\d{2}){2})$/
```

Here's railroad diagram for this

[image: New RegEx Railroad]

Note that `1` and `2` in the diagram refer to respective capturing group.

[**Demo on RegEx101**](https://regex101.com/r/HSqiQR/2)

Although, this answer only explains about one RegEx, other RegExes can be modified in the similar way.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, and for introducing the Back-reference, the other regex can greatly improve.

Comment: Out of curiosity, from which site did you generate that railroad diagram? cannot find it in regex101.

Comment: @vims I've used [atom plugin](https://atom.io/packages/regex-railroad-diagram) to generate diagram.